# Trying to display recent posts outside wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to display recent posts on my main website which is outside wordpress, my blog is actually blog.domain.com and the directory root of the wordpress is in my main website if this help, here is my code:

```
// Include the wp-load'er
include('blog_subdomain/wp-load.php');

// Get the last 10 posts
// Returns posts as arrays instead of get_posts' objects
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => 10
));

// Do something with them
echo '<ul>';
foreach($recent_posts as $post) {
    echo '<li><a href="', get_permalink($post['ID']), '">', $post['post_title'], '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

But when I try to access my page where I want the recent post to be displayed it redirects me to the blog address.

Comment: The way you should do that is by using a php curl request, or use one of the file functions like file_get_contents(), then set a token and header to verify and accept request only from your sites outside WordPress.

Comment: Yes the methods which I found on google are I think outdated, they are from 2012 and so on and Wordpress maybe did some changes that's why is not working, thank you for the tips.

Comment: Also, here's a quick tip:1.Get the posts from your wp database table on the wordpress site. 2. Save it to a file ( or connect to dropbox and save it there ), or even better,create an ajax cross domain request and save it to the site database outside wordpress, 3. Use htacess to restrict who can access the script generating the posts and saving it to a file, database or dropbox. 4. Retrieve the posts in your site database outside WordPress, then display it.

Comment: I found something more simple, I just copy and pasted this code inside wordpress root directory and there is working, then I access the file which is calling the wp api with file get contents outside wordpress and now is working.

Comment: Alright, good job 